# Adverb position(by deliberately doing.....)

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbs, word-order, grammatical-roles, gerund-phrases

I have searched the definition of *contrarily* to know its usage. I found this

> A child who behaves contrarily behaves badly by deliberately doing the opposite of what is wanted or expected.

I understood the meaning of this it shows contrast.

But, I am now confused about the adverb's position in this sentence ("by deliberately doing"), because it is in between the preposition *by* and gerund *doing*.

Could you please help to understand it?

Comment: I hope someone carefully answers your question. Why do you you think the adverb-gerund word order is wrong?

Comment: I thought adverb can't modify a gerund in sentence.

Comment: The fact that a verb is in the gerund does not make it "unmodifiable" by adverbs. It still remain a verb.

Comment: Actually, we read adverb can modify verb, adjective and other adverb in sentence. And gerund act as noun that's why I got confused in this sentence.

Comment: Well, it preserves many features of a verb. Consider: _He **deliberately does** the opposite of what is wanted or expected._

Comment: In this clause - "He deliberately does the opposite of what is wanted or expected". It is a adverb of manner, showed "How something is done" in this sentence.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does within the prepositional phrase [by deliberately doing the opposite of what is wanted or expected], too. _Doing_ still denotes an action, and _deliberately_ shows the manner in which this action is carried out.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more. "Walking quickly is good exercise". is it correct? can I conclude that gerund can be modify by an adverb? it look like noun but not true noun because it shows whole activity itself.

Comment: Read this to understand the [difference between gerunds used as nouns and present participles used as prepositional objects](https://courses.dcs.wisc.edu/wp/grammar/present-and-past-participles/). That said, I would rather say "Walking **fast** is good exercise."

Comment: @user461735 I'm afraid you've misunderstood gerunds, which isn't a great surprise because so much instructional material oversimplifies gerunds in ways that confuse and mislead. The "acts like a noun" nonsense is deceptive weasel wording; these are nonfinite clauses fulfilling grammatical roles like subjects and objects. That doesn't make them nouns. Because gerunds are only ever verbs, they can only ever be modified by adverbs, never by adjectives. If an *-ing* word **can** be modified by an adjective, it is never a gerund, only a noun. Compare *easy living* with *living easily*.

Answer (score 3):

The position of *deliberately* is not determined by the preposition *by*, but by the verb *doing* which happens to be in the gerund. Adverbs of manner, like ***deliberately*** is, can go before the verb. They

> sometimes go in *mid position* <sub>[that is, *after the subject and **before the verb***]</sub>, if the adverb is not the most important part of the clause or ***if the object is very long***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position))

In your sentence, the object of *doing* is indeed long. To say

> ... by doing [the opposite of what is wanted or expected] *deliberately*. 
> <sub>*[object]*</sub>

would be more clumsy. Putting *deliberately* after *doing* is not a good idea, as verbs should not be separated from their objects.

> An adverb of manner cannot be put between a verb and its direct object. The adverb must be placed either before the verb or at the end of the clause. ([ef.co.uk](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-manner/))

Answer (score 3):

Adverbs can go in a number of positions, but here it's not *by* which is moving the adverb, but the particular use of *doing.*

> 1. He annoys me by behaving badly.
> 2. He annoys me by doing that deliberately.
> 3. He annoys me by doing what I tell him not to deliberately.
> 4. He annoys me by deliberately doing what I tell him not to.
> 5. He annoys me by doing deliberately what I tell him not to.

Normally, an adverb goes after the verb it modifies. as in 1 and 2.

Where the verb has a long object phrase as in 3, "what I tell him not to" rather than a pronoun *that,* the adverb almost certainly needs to be moved. In 3, the closest verb to *deliberately* is *tell*, and it is **that** verb which *deliberately* modifies. You have told him something deliberately, and he doesn't comply. The implication is that if he will comply if you don't tell him deliberately!

The desired meaning in 3 is made clearer in 4 by moving the adverb closer to the verb it needs to modify: *doing.* In this case, the idiomatic position is before the verb, *by deliberately doing.*

The order in 5 is possible and understandable, but it's unusual and no longer idiomatic (if it ever was).

A further consideration might be a transitive-verb sentence like

> 6. He annoys me deliberately.
> 7. He deliberately annoys me.

Here, although the meaning is the same (the annoying is intentional), there is a difference in emphasis: moving the adverb forward in the sentence — even separating the verb from its subject — raises its importance.

This doesn't work with an intransitive verb. You can't have "*He badly behaves;" it must be "✓He behaves badly," although other adverbs can be inserted into **that** sentence in a variety of places. Note that *badly* modifies *behaves* and **always** comes after the verb.

> 8. He behaves badly deliberately.
> 9. He behaves deliberately badly.
> 10. He deliberately behaves badly.

Here, 8 is a bit stilted not particularly good style, and there is a difference in emphasis between 9 and 10.